# asp.net c# website form actions after 24 hrs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net c# website which members complete a form which is stored in sql server. After 24 hrs, I would like to send a notification to a specific group of users if the form status has NOT changed. Is this achievable from within asp.net?? Any help is appreciated

Comment: what sort of notification?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to specify what kind of notification. But anyways, there's all sorts of [ways to create a background job](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) in ASP.NET.

Comment: a notification like stackexchange unread messages preferably

Comment: Alright, well I've shown you how to execute background jobs. You clearly have an idea of how to use SQL Server to store information. What exactly are you looking for from us? To right your site? That's not what we're here for. You've got the information in front of you to make an attempt at solving your problem. I suggest you start working on it, then if you run into a specific issue with your implementation you can bring it back here.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it several times and there are many ways to do it. One simple way is to check every X minutes if you need to send any notifications. If so, you send them.

For example: every 60 minutes you check if there are any forms that have been on the same status for 24hs. If so, you send a notification.

If you have full control of the server, I would recommend you to create a Windows Service to perform this job. ASP.NET was not built for long running tasks so that's why I'm suggesting to create a Windows Service.

One more thing, create a log table for this task so every time you send a notification, you add a row on that table. That's gonna help you debug any issues you might have. Also, remember to mark the rows where you have already notified the customer to avoid sending a notification twice. I always like to add a double check before sending the notification.

Comment: ok thanks i will do some research on it